# Is there a media server with player app for Android TV that can take screenshots?

Tags: android, media-player, dlna, android-tv

I tried Plex, and it can stream Dolby Vision (the whole point why I'm even attempting to do this without PC connected to the TV), and could even control the UI with a PS5 controller. But I'm an obsessive screenshot-taker, and it's a dealbreaker if I can't do that. I'd imagine mapping one of the keys on the TV remote or controller to it. I don't seem to be able to take regular "Android screenhots" on the TV. DLNA is fine too, it's the player that's not superuser enough.